# The most occuring number in structure(array)

Tags: c++, c, arrays, structure

I cant find out whats wrong with this part of my program, i want to find out most occuring number in my structure(array), but it finds only the last number :/

```
void Daugiausiai(int n)
{
    int max = 0;
    int sk;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            int kiek = 0;
        for(int j=0; j < n; j++){
            if(A[i].datamet == A[j].datamet){
                kiek++;
                if(kiek > max){
                    max = kiek;
                    sk = A[i].datamet;

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

ps. its only a part of my code

Comment: have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is the script? This is a C program.

Comment: jhamon, the PROGRAM (not script, sorry iqstatic, im not a programmer, im just beginner) is working, it just does not find the most occuring number.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us enough of your code, but it is likely that you are not looking at the real result of your function. The result, `sk` is local to the function and you don't return it. If you have global variable that is also named `sk`, it will not be touched by `Daugiausiai`.

In the same way, you pass the number of elements in your struct array, but work on a global struct. It is good practice to "encapsulate"  functions so that they receive the data they work on as arguments and return a result. Your function should therefore pass both array length and array and return the result.

(Such an encapsulation doesn't work in all cases, but here, it has the benefit that you can use the same function for many different arrays of the same structure tape.)

It is also enough to test whether the current number of elements is more than the maximum so far after your counting loop.

Putting all this together:

```
struct Data {
    int datamet;
};

int Daugiausiai(const struct Data A[], int n)
{
    int max = 0;
    int sk;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int kiek = 0;

        // Count occurrences
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(A[i].datamet == A[j].datamet) kiek++;
        }

        // Check for maximum
        if (kiek > max) {
            max = kiek;
            sk = A[i].datamet;
        }
    }

    return sk;
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
struct Data A[6] = {{1}, {2}, {1}, {4}, {1}, {2}};
int n = Daugiausiai(A, 6);

printf("%d\n", n);    // 1
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iz0LiPAK  here is my full code, can you look at the end where i write     fr << sk << endl;  i get an error  Use of undeclared identifier 'sk' , but I used it ? :/

Comment: The error refers to the `Isvedimas` function. There is no symbol called `sk` there. The definition of `sk` in `Daugiausiai` is local to that function. A definition is only valid witin the block of curly braces `{...}` where it is declared.

Comment: Is there any way to print 'sk' in Isvedimas function without losing information that is saved in it?

Comment: As I said: It is best to provide the data to each function. If a function has a result, return it. Then print that returned value, as in the last block of code in my example. That's the main mistake of your original function: It calculates a value, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: when i try to return (return sk;) i get an error: Void function 'Daugiausiai' should not return a value.

Comment: Yes, you must, of course make it a function returning `int`. A `void` function doesn't return anything; it just _does_ something. But the element that occurs most often is clearly a result that you should return. Again, look at my example or at Exhauzt's below.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qPycTjrM so i make it like this. but still i get two errors. After last } i get : "Control may reach end of non-void function". And at first for cycle i get error: "Loop will run at most once(loop increment never executed)"   and where do i have to put int `n = Daugiausiai(A, n);`

Comment: Sorry for these question, that may look dumb to you, but Im a beginner so... :)

Comment: You really need to stydy basic C more. `return` does two things: It immediately returns from the function and it passes the result value of the function type to the caller. Your version returns early and cuts the loop short. The last statement will not be reached unless `n` is zero. In a function that returns a value, your last stamement should be a `return`. (In a `void` function, the `return` statement can't have a value. It can also be omitted as last stamenet in the function.)

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing wrong with being a beginner, but you should take some time to learn the fundamentals of C and programming. SO is not the right place to ask such trivial questions. We can help you with concrete issues you have, but we can't learn C for you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you had english variable names, so I could read them a bit better ^^. What should your paramter `n` do? Is that the array-length? And what should yout funtion do? It has no return value or something.

```
int getMostOccuring(int array[], int length)
{
   int current_number;
   int current_count = 0;
   int most_occuring_number;
   int most_occuring_count = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
      current_number = array[i];
      current_count = 0;

      for (int j = i; j < length; j++)
      {
          int test_number = array[j];

          if (test_number == current_number)
          {
             current_count ++;

             if (current_count > most_occuring_count)
             {
                most_occuring_number = current_number;
                most_occuring_count = current_count;
             }
          }
      }
   }

   return most_occuring_number;
}
```

this should work and return the most occuring number in the given array (it has a bad runtime, but is very simple and good to understand).